# IDApython and IDA-decompiler commenting

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, hexrays, idapro-sdk

Looking at the functions exposed by `idaapi` I see that functions like the following are exposed.

```
get_user_cmt
set_user_cmt
save_user_cmts
```

As these functions are exposed I'm hoping that I have a way to add comments onto the hex-rays decompiler using a script. I looked around a bit and could not find examples using these functions.

[EDIT]

set_user_cmt seems to take 2 arguments, of which the second is the comment and the first is an instance of `treeloc_t`. However, I'm not too sure how to use it. Using the following leads to an orphan comment.

```
idaapi.set_user_cmt(idaapi.treeloc_t(5), "asdf")
```

Comment: Ask their support for examples?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure that it answers your question, but probably it will give you some direction : https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/vds4.py

Comment: Just for reference : you will probably find more information on treeloc_t here, in hexrays.hpp file : https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/hexrays_8hpp_source.shtml . I'd be glad to provide more complete solution but unfortunately I don't have working hex-rays now.

Answer (score 2):

The [`treeloc_t` constructor](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi.treeloc_t-class.html) does not accept an EA, and you need to specify the comment preciser:

```
ea = idaapi.get_screen_ea()
cfunc = idaapi.decompile(ea)
tl = idaapi.treeloc_t()
tl.ea = ea
tl.itp = idaapi.ITP_SEMI
cfunc.set_user_cmt(tl, "Test comment")
cfunc.save_user_cmts()
```

You can find more info about the precisers in [hexrays.hpp](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/group__type.shtml#ga219c95f85c085e6f539b8d3b96074aee). Not all precisers work everywhere. For example, the above code uses `ITP_SEMI`, which comments after a semicolon: it will result in an orphan comment if you use it on an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve a similar thing with [ida-batch_decompile](https://github.com/tintinweb/ida-batch_decompile). The basic idea is to annotate and decompile the target from commandline (but it also comes with a menu entry; acting as a plugin or idascript)

It currently annotates functions with a textual description of guessed stack variable sizes and xrefs. To do so it adds a function comment block with `SetFunctionCmt(addr, txtcomment, 0)` ([see code](https://github.com/tintinweb/ida-batch_decompile/blob/master/ida_batch_decompile.py#L157)) and once all functions are annotated it decompiles the target binary to pseudocode (optionally also decompiles resolvable imports). Note that atm it is not capable of annotating decompiled lines but I am looking into having that in the future.

Here's an example for `dbghelp.c`

```
//----- (03052800) --------------------------------------------------------
// **** Variables ****
// * stack size: 20
// {"diff_size": 4, "offset_text": "[bp+0h]", "size": 4, "name": " s", "offset": 0}
// {"diff_size": 4, "offset_text": "[bp+4h]", "size": 4, "name": " r", "offset": 4}
// {"diff_size": 4, "offset_text": "[bp+8h]", "size": 4, "name": "arg_0", "offset": 8}
// {"diff_size": 4, "offset_text": "[bp+Ch]", "size": 4, "name": "dwBytes", "offset": 12}
// {"diff_size": 4, "offset_text": "[bp+10h]", "size": 4, "name": "arg_8", "offset": 16}
// *******************
// ***** XREFS *****
// * # 1
// sub_30733D0+30
// *******************
int __stdcall sub_3052800(int a1, SIZE_T dwBytes, int a3)
{
  int result; // eax@17
  HANDLE v4; // eax@21
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [idc.MakeComm](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#MakeComm) or [idc.MakeRptCmt](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#MakeRptCmt) functions. For example:

```
MakeComm(address, 'My comment')
```

Comment: I don't believe that can be used to apply comments on Hex-Rays decompilations.